# Serializing a non django model with Django Rest Frame

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a django model with DRF that either sends a object state payload after creation, or an error payload. When I try to do something similar, then I get the following error message:

`File "/Users/user/projects/bowling-game/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 527, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/Users/user/projects/bowling-game/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 683, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/Users/user/projects/bowling-game/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 683, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/Users/user/projects/bowling-game/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 510, in to_representation
    fields = self._readable_fields
  File "/Users/user/projects/bowling-game/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/user/projects/bowling-game/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 376, in _readable_fields
    field for field in self.fields.values()
  File "/Users/user/projects/bowling-game/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 363, in fields
    for key, value in self.get_fields().items():
  File "/Users/user/projects/bowling-game/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 997, in get_fields
    serializer_class=self.__class__.__name__
AssertionError: Class ErrorSerializer missing "Meta" attribute`

My models are given below:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model, object):
    # Encapsulates all error objects.
    errors= []

    def add_error(self, error_object):
        """Appends the error to the list of errors."""
        self.errors.append(error_object)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        app_label = 'game'


class GameRegistration(BaseModel):
    """Instance of this class represents the user playing the bowling game."""

    game_id = models.CharField(max_length=32,
        help_text='Unique bowling game id', primary_key=True,
        default=functools.partial(random_string, char_length=16))
    #  I will set the request.user to set the details later on, but not now.
    user_name = models.CharField(help_text='unique username', default='test', max_length=32)
    created_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['game_id'])
        ]


class Error(object):
    """
    An instance of this class encapsulates the error code and the message to be
    returned.
    """
    def __init__(self, error_code, error_message):
        self.error_code = error_code
        self.error_message = error_message

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}:{}'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.__dict__)
```

My serializer implementation

```
class BaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer, object):
    pass

class ErrorSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    """Representation of any error resulting in any of the operation."""
    error_code = serializers.IntegerField()
    error_message = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        ordering=('error_code',)

class GameRegistrationSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    """Serializer representation of game instance."""
    game_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)


    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return {
            'game_id': str(instance.game_id),
            'created': instance.created_timestamp
        }

    class Meta:
        model = models.GameRegistration
        fields = ('game_id', 'created')
        read_only_fields = ('game_id', 'created')
```

I want a way to serialize `errors` json array within the payload. It is not bound to any django model. It encapsulates all the errors associated with other django models. The idea is that if I am able to create `GameRegistration`, then I would return a following payload

`{
   'game_id': 'ABCDabcd1234',
   'created': '<created stamp>'
}`

In case of an error, I would return a payload as follows:

`{
    'errors': {
       'error_code': 500,
       'error_message': 'Server error' 
    }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inherit `BaseSerializer` from `Serializer` class instead of from `ModelSerializer`. Hence the `BaseSerializer` will be like

```
class BaseSerializer(serializers.Serializer, object):
    pass
```

The problem with `ModelSerializer` is, it expect a `Meta` class with atleast `two` fields which are `fields` and `model`

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: @JPG to you know why this is needed. In all other modules `class PagesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):` works